# Minecraft Triggers Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Whenever a trigger command happens it shows in chat "Triggered *objective name here*" i was wondering if there was a way to make this message not show but not disable sendCommandFeedback. Would be very helpful

Comment: On a server, op players are the only ones who can see that. Probably doesn't help your situation much though.

Comment: *(...) **not** disable sendCommandFeedback* - the dupe doesn't answer this.

Answer (score 0):

#### There's no way to disable player command output.

Whenever a player issues a command, they will see an output message. If it is on a server as well, all the server operators and the console will also be able to view the output.

The `CommandBlockOutput` gamerule doesn't work on player command output, but only on command blocks.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using command blocks; from [this video:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypWPneG3fDs) use /gamerule commandBlockOutput false